# Convert multiple images with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert **all my PNGs to PNG** using **ImageMagick** (I need this because AndroidStudio has some issue with the original PNGs. ImageMagick is able to fix this issue by re-exporting the PNG.)

If I do: `convert a.png a.png` it works.

But how do I do this for many files (including files from sub directories)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows users -- you can try this in a `cmd.exe` window:

```
for %i in (*.png *\*.png *\*\*.png *\*\*\*.png) do (
   convert.exe %i %~pni---repaired.png
)
```

This will loop through the current dir's PNGs as well as the ones in the sub directories 3 levels deep.

You have to make sure that your `convert.exe` really is the one from ImageMagick -- set up your environment variable `%PATH%` accordingly. Otherwise you may run into an error when the command wants to use the identically named *disk format conversion `convert.exe` command*.

If unsure, use the full path to the IM `convert.exe`, e.g.:

```
D:\programs\imagemagick-install-dir\convert.exe %i %~pni---repaired.png
```

**Also, remember:** If you put the above command into a `*.bat` file, you have to double up each occurrence of `%`. So `%i` from the direct command becomes `%%i` in the batch file!

---

If you are on Vista/Windows7/2008/8 (or on Windows XP with the **[Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546)** installed) you'll have the `ForFiles.exe` available, which can be used to loop through files:

```
forfiles.exe   ^
  /p <path>    ^
  /m *.png     ^
  /s           ^
  /C "convert.exe @file @fname---repaired.png"
```

Comment: @AlexandruCircus: Which one  of the two did you try?

Comment: I tried the second one and worked (forfiles). The only thing I  changed was this: /c "cmd /c convert.exe @file @file". I added cmd /c command...(and also overwritten the original files - I don't need duplicates)

Comment: forfiles /p "pathToMyImagesDirs" /m *.png /s /c "cmd /c convert @file @file"

Comment: @AlexandruCircus: I'm always shy to overwrite the originals... just in case something goes wrong. *"Better shy than sorry"* :)

Comment: what if it's combining multiple input images into a single output?  Can't use a loop in that case, but can't specify multiple input images without globbing either?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command. Start it from the top-most directory from where you want to convert all images:

```
find . -name "*.png"     \
| while read image; do   \
     convert "${image}" "${image/.png/---repaired.png}
  done
```

***Caveats:*** Should you have PNG files with the suffix `.PNG` or `.pNg` or similar, the command will not work for these. For such cases, the command needs some modifications...

Comment: I've created a .bat file containing this command and placed it in the top-most dir and run it as admin but nothing happens. I must specify I'm not so familiar with batches.

Comment: @AlexandruCircus: This command is not for `*.bat`. It is for Linux, Unix and Mac OS X. You didn't state that you are on Windows. I'll have a shot at a Windows version later or tomorrow (I'm currently far away from a Windows box with ImageMagick installed...).